# JFreeChart: overlapping bars in XY chart that have the same value

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart, overlap

I have this problem where 2 bars from a different series overlap each other when they have the same value. And I would like 1 of both on top of the other.
Unfortunately, I want the one that is now in the back, up front :

[image]

I already tried changing the order of the category expression, but to no avail.
Anyone can tell me how I can get the orange bar on top of the blue one please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [`DatasetRenderingOrder`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/DatasetRenderingOrder.html):

```
XYPlot plot = jFreeChart.getXYPlot();
plot.setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD); // or reverse
```

or

```
plot.setSeriesRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);
```

If neither works, it isn't a bad idea to use [stacked bar](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jfreechart/createStackedBarChart.html).

Comment: plot.setSeriesRenderingOrder(SeriesRenderingOrder.FORWARD);

that's it ! thanks a lot.

Comment: @sven-deckers It's a pleasure~ And don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the factory default, use [`ClusteredXYBarRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/ClusteredXYBarRenderer.html), which "displays bars for different series values at the same *x* next to each other."

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
Maybe I should have mentioned I'm working with iReport 3.7. 
The ClusteredXYBarRenderer is unavailble as chart type.
Or can I work around this in my chartcustomizer class ?